# Similar google emails check for duplicate

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Google (and maybe others) treat `foo.bar@gmail.com` and `foobar@gmail.com` as the same mail box.

Suppose I have a user email in my db:

`foo.bar@gmail.com`

And I want to check that a new user that tries to register with `foobar@gmail.com` will not be able to register since that email already exists.

The scenario could be the other way around where a user already registered with `foobar@gmail.com` and a new one tries to register with `foo.bar@gmail.com`. for my purposes the emails are equal, and must be "unique".

I have tried

```
declare @email nvarchar(255);
set @newEmail = 'foobar@gmail.com' -- or 'foo.bar@gmail.com'

select * from Users where REPLACE(Users.Email, '.', '') = REPLACE(@newEmail, '.', '')
```

but this seems not so efficient and *might* conflict with the domain part (gmail.com).

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: May I suggest that you just compare the raw email string?  After all, `foo.bar@gmail.com` would not be treated the same as `foobar@gmail.com`, as far as I know.

Comment: Gmail does treat `foo+bar@gmail.com` and `foo@gmail.com` as the same though.

Comment: @DavidG Perhaps, but in general, with other domains, I'm not sure we can assume this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Indeed, I was just pointing out how Gmail does it (and a few others, but not too many.) You are absolutely right however, that OP probably shouldn't be checking this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a computed column to remove any dots from the gmail addresses and then create a unique key on that column.

For example:

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE (
    Email VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY,
    ShortEmail AS CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),CASE 
        WHEN Email LIKE '%@gmail.com' OR Email LIKE '%@googlemail.com' 
        THEN REPLACE(LEFT(Email,CHARINDEX('@',Email)),'.','')+SUBSTRING(Email,CHARINDEX('@',Email)+1,LEN(Email)) 
        ELSE Email 
    END) UNIQUE
)
INSERT INTO @Test (Email) VALUES ('a.b@gmail.com'),('a.b@c.com'),('ab@c.com'),('ab.c@gmail.com'),('abc@gmail.com')
```

Comment: Nice idea. but after testing the above the last insert `abc@gmail.com` causes: `Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ__#BB8DE32__BD56945139D5D8FD'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.@Test'. The duplicate key value is (abc@gmail.com).` and if I read your code correctly this should not happen?

Comment: That is the intended behavior, because "abc@gmail.com" would be a duplicate for "ab.c@gmail.com".

Comment: OK, I see it now. Thank you.